# R - Unexpected behavior when typechecking columns of tidyverse data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm working with some data that has hundreds of covariates, so I decided to write some functions to make pre-processing much faster and cleaner (like scaling certain numeric variables). An important part of all of these functions is type-checking the columns before I apply a particular function to them.

Here is my function for scaling continuous columns:

```
# rm (vector): names of columns not to be scaled
scale.continuous <- function(df, rm=NULL) {
  cols <- setdiff(colnames(df), rm)
  for(col in cols) {
    if(is.numeric(df[,col])){
      df[,col] <- as.numeric(scale(df[,col]))
    }
  }
  df
}
```

This works perfectly fine if I load the data frame using `read.csv()`, but the data I have is huge so the speed boost of using `read_csv()` from readr/tidyverse is significant. Unfortunately, if I load my data using `read_csv()` all of my functions break.

I narrowed down the issue to the type-checking, specifically when type-checking a column I am accessing by a **string of its column name**. Here's some code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
# When using read.csv()
> is.numeric(df$col)
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(df[,"col"])
[1] TRUE

# When using read_csv()
> is.numeric(df$col)
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(df[,"col"])
[1] FALSE
```

I realized the issue here was that indexing the dataframe with a string the way I do above returns a tibble instead of a regular list like other methods of indexing do. What I don't understand is why this behavior exists, why `as.numeric()` (or any type-check) does not work with a tibble and in general why there is this difference in the way the default and tidyverse dataframes are constructed. Also, it would be nice to know if there is a parameter I can change in `read_csv()` that will make the behavior of this type of indexing the same as with a default dataframe.

---

I should mention, I realize there are probably better ways of writing this code (for example, just using `df$"col"` to index fixes the issue), but I still don't understand what the root of the issue was with my first approach. I am now working with much larger data sets that require much more involved pre-processing than what I have been used to in the past so I want to have as complete an understanding of the data structures I am using as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Tibbles have a slightly different default behaviour than regular data frames when using the `[` extracting function which can be a bit of a gotcha. Specifically `df[,"col"]` on a tibble will return a one column tibble whereas on a regular data frame it will return a vector.  So you need to use:

```
df[["col"]]
```

Or explicitly state that you want to coerce to the lowest dimension and do:

```
df[, "col", drop = TRUE]
```

From the documentation:

> df[, j] returns a tibble; it does not automatically extract the column
>   inside. df[, j, drop = FALSE] is the default.